# Why can't I print this information from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a problem with printing out information that is stored in a database. I have inserted multiple entries into a single form using arrays but once the information is stored into the database successfully and I try and retrieve the data, I am not able to see any information. It appears completely blank. The image below shows the data that is being inserted into the form. There are multiple entries that are all allocated into an array. Then the array is split and re-inserted back into the database.

http://oi66.tinypic.com/r89xjl.jpg

The next pics show the data being retrieved from the form after entering the database (data inside database also shown below)-

http://oi63.tinypic.com/n5nghy.jpg (data from form being retrieved "editjapplications.php?id=1")

http://oi68.tinypic.com/2csgqaf.jpg (the MySQL database of the original form)

http://oi68.tinypic.com/2m5gm8l.jpg (the MySQL database with the three entries)

http://oi67.tinypic.com/oswtbc.jpg (from the form field returning blank spaces after being retrieved - "editjapplications.php?id=1")

Here is the code that is returning the blank spaces as seen in the last image (the one right above this sentence) -

```
     <?php

$query33 = "SELECT * FROM emprecords WHERE id ='$id'";
$record_set33 = $dbs->prepare($query33);
$record_set33 -> execute();
$row22 = $record_set33->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$id=$row22["id"];

$first_name=$row22["first_name"];

$middle_names1=$row22["middle_names"];
$last_name=$row22["last_name"];
$full_names = $first_name." ".$middle_names." ".$last_name;

$idz = $_GET["idz"];
//$_SESSION["idz"] = $idz;
//$query = "SELECT * FROM emprecords WHERE id ='$id'";
//$record_set = $dbs->prepare($query);
//$record_set -> execute();
//$row = $record_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellspacing='0' style='margin-top:22px width='900'>
<colgroup>
<col span='2'>
</colgroup>";
$full_names1 = $_GET["full_name"];  

$query11 = "SELECT * FROM education WHERE full_name ='$full_names1' AND idz='$idz'";
$listAHI2 = $dbs ->prepare($query11);
$listAHI2 -> execute();

while ($row22 = $listAHI2 ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$full_names1 = $row22["full_name"];
$name_1 = $row22["name_1"];
$idz = $row22["idz"];
echo $full_names;
echo $name_1;
echo $idz;
$institution_1 = $row22["institution_1"];
echo $institution_1;
$instaddress_1 = $row22["instaddress_1"];
echo $instaddress_1;
$monthto_1 = $row22["monthto_1"];
echo $monthto_1;
$toyear_1 = $row22["toyear_1"];

$monthto_1_1 = $row22["monthto_1_1"];

$toyear_1_1 = $row22["toyear_1_1"];
$graduate_1 = $row22["graduate_1"];
$averages_1 = $row22["averages_1"];

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td valign='top'><input type='input' id='name_1' name='name_1[]' value='$name_1' maxlength='30' size='20'><td>";
echo "<td><select name='institution_1[]' id='institution_1'> <option>$institution_1</option>"; 
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
}    
echo "<select></td>";

echo "<td valign='top'><input type='text' id='instaddress_1' name='instaddress_1[]' value='$instaddress_1' maxlength='15' size='15'><td>";
echo "<td><select name='monthto_1[]' id='monthto'> <option>$monthto_1</option>"; 
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id4'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
}    
echo "</select></td>";

echo "<td><select name='toyear[]' id='toyear'> <option>$toyear_1</option>"; 
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY year desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id5'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
}    
echo "</select></td>";

echo "<td><select name='monthto1[]' id='monthto1'> <option>$monthto_1_1</option>"; 
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id6'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
}    
echo "</select></td>";

echo "<td><select name='toyear1[]' id='toyear1'> <option>$toyear_1_1</option>"; 
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY year desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id7'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
}    
echo "</select></td>";
echo "<td>$graduate_1<td>";
echo "<td valign='top'><input type='text' id='averages' name='averages[]' value='$averages_1' maxlength='100' size='3'></td>";
$query = "SELECT * FROM education WHERE full_name ='$full_name'";
$listAHI = $dbs ->prepare($query);
$listAHI -> execute();
while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$idz = $row["idz"];
echo "<td> <a href='editeducation.php?full_name=$full_name&idz=$idz' name='Edit' value='Edit'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td> <a href='deleteeducation.php?full_name=$full_name&idz=$idz' name='Delete' value='Delete'>Delete</a></td>";
echo  "<td valign='top'> <a href='deleteedcuation'name='delete' value='Delete'</a></td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Where did I go wrong with my code? Why is it not returning the data from the database? It should have 3 rows of data printed out in the columns below the form field. It doesn't even contain 1 single row of data. The data has successfully entered the database in all the correct fields as can be seen in the screenshot image above (http://oi68.tinypic.com/2m5gm8l.jpg).

I am confused as to why the data does not show up when I try and retrieve the form details by going to the link — "editjapplications.php?id=1" — although all the data has been entered into the various fields and all 3 rows should be showing on that page — and yet not even one row of data is being displayed!

What am I missing?

Comment: sorry about the title...happened due to frustration...anyone looking to help out?

Comment: it should be a trivial matter...but i dont get why its not working...sos!

Comment: have you done any debugging? what kind of errors do you have?

Comment: i did do debugging...it returns blank - " " for anything after the "$full_name" variable...where did my code go wrong? i showed the database already with all the input

Comment: by adding the pictures, you make it difficult for us to help you, probably the reason of the downvotes

Comment: i just wanted to show the data that was inserted to the database and the code should explain it to u ...can u figure out why its not printing out any of the data except for the full name?

Comment: $institution_1 = $row22["institution_1"];
echo $institution_1;
$instaddress_1 = $row22["instaddress_1"];
echo $instaddress_1;
$monthto_1 = $row22["monthto_1"]; 
echo $monthto_1; - how come I am not able to print out the variables that are echoed? SOS!

Comment: anyone willing to help out here?

Comment: Not a good idea to use `SELECT *` and direct interpolation of variables into query strings. PDO allows you to put in placeholders and bind those to variables so that you aren't open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

To debug all of your php code add this to very top of your php code (right after the openings tags):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will show the errors if any in your php code.

Comment: i am working on it now...lets see if it works or not

Comment: thnx guys i got it to work...i should have used the debugger!